# How to configure autoscaling on docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I would like to know how to configure this tool to start with a minimum number of nodes and grow to a maximum number of nodes when it is required.

Should I use another tool or can docker swarm solve this for me?

Comment: According to a Proposal/Feature Request in the [official Swarm repo](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1663), the [dockercloud-haproxy](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy#running-with-docker-swarmmode-swarm-mode) tool looks like it works with Swarm out of the box, but I have not confirmed.

Comment: @smeeb does that tool include autoscaling?

Comment: dockercloud-haproxy distributes requests along existing containers, it does not aid in auto-scaling.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Short answer**: There is no easy way to do this with Docker Swarm for now.

Docker Swarm (or Swarm mode) does not support **auto-scaling** machines out of the box. You'd need to use another solution for that like `docker-machine` to create machines (with docker) on your infrastructure and link these to the existing Swarm cluster (with `docker swarm join`).

This will involve a lot of scripting but the idea is to monitor the cluster for CPU / Memory / Network usage (with `top` or `monit`) and once it goes beyond a threshold (say *70%* of total cluster resources), you trigger a script calling `docker-machine` to scale up the cluster. Using the same idea you can also scale down by **draining** and **removing** nodes (preferably `Agent` nodes) from the existing swarm cluster once your are below the lower threshold.

You need to make sure you are monitoring for sustained resource usage if you want to use this criteria or you will have your Infrastructure spawning and destroying nodes from the frequent and sudden changes in resource usage.

You can define a lower bound and an upper bound for machines in the cluster to keep things under control.

Note that Swarm requires at least 3 `Manager` nodes (recommended 5) to maintain a quorum for the Distributed Consensus algorithm. So **the minimum recommended lower bound is 5 nodes** (which you can extend with `Agent` nodes as resources are incrementally being used by services).

To some extent, you can also take a look at [Docker InfraKit](https://github.com/docker/infrakit) or [Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform) for *Infrastructure automation* and *Health monitoring*.

> **Update**: There is now a promising cross-platform autoscaler that supports Swarm Mode **task auto-scaling**: [Orbiter](https://github.com/gianarb/orbiter). Although still nothing out-of-the-box yet for service/machine autoscaling.

Comment: Thanks @abronan! As I understand, nodes can be scalable only with external tools. What about containers? would be possible to autoscale containers? Or should I have use another tool such as kubernetes?

Comment: @CelsoAgra AFAIK, there is the `docker service scale` command (or its `docker-compose` counterpart) but you also have to trigger the scaling using stats on incoming requests or cpu usage for example. Kubernetes indeed has a [pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaling/) based on resource usage so this can fit your use case :)

Comment: @abronan (or anyone) do you know if the Docker community has a built-in auto-scaler planned on the Docker Roadmap? I feel like this would be a heavily-utilized feature if Docker supported this right out of the box...

Comment: Also @abronan any chance you can explain: (1) what component is typically monitoring cluster-wide resources and, most importantly, (2) what component runs the `docker-machine` commands?

Comment: We needed autoscaling based on metrics stored in prometheus. We built a service which uses docker API to scale based on metrics from prometheus https://github.com/sahajsoft/docker-swarm-service-autoscaler

Answer (score 3):

Scaling up is pretty easy. You can just keep on scheduling containers when needed. Then you just create a script that looks for pending container and scales up the cluster. For example if you're using the official CloudFormation template on aws for swarm, you can just change the desired number on the autoscaling group. An example iteration script could looks like this:

```
services=$(docker service ls --format '{{.ID}}')
for service in $services; do
  tasks=$(docker service ps $service --format '{{.ID}}')
  for task in $tasks; do
    if docker inspect $task --format '{{.Status}}' | grep 'insufficient resources' 1>/dev/null; then
      scale-up-cmd
    fi
  done
done
```