# Can containers in Swarm Mode be automaticaly raised when the Load is high?

Tags: azure, web-applications, scaling, docker-swarm-mode, docker-for-windows

So we are getting started with Docker Containers and Swarm Mode on Windows. Currently, we have installed Docker for Windows, enabled the Swarm mode in Single-Node Mode, Scaled sevices etc.

Now we are looking, if there is a way to **automaticaly create new containers**, on the node(s) when the load, on the existing containers, is high.

There is a way to monitor the load on the Nodes, for example if the memory on the Node is high. I'm aware of the fact that there can be some automated Nodecreation, that will host new containers, if the load on the Nodes is high, refering to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE0qVTGC6MA) example of doing this. But is there a way to **monitor containers** on a container host/swarm?

We are aiming to host a WebApp running on a microsoft/iis image which currently works fine. But we wanted to know if there is a way to handle the possible incoming load without this leading the system  to fail, or having to manualy create new containers.

The current enviroment is a local test VM on our servers and **the goal** is to do all this stuff in a MS Azure VM running also Windows Server 2016.

Also what would you suggest as a tool/solution for creating traffic load on a website? Somehow we will have to test the whole concept.

I also wanted to add that I am a newbie with Docker and Swarm mode, so there might be a posibility that I'm putting this in words down the wrong way.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!  :)

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668621/how-to-configure-autoscaling-on-docker-swarm

Comment: Swarm on Windows does not support running more then 1 container with host port mapping, plus it does not support routing mesh. That makes it impossible to scale container instances regardless wether swarm itself provides this capabilities. Routing mesh shall be coming this year which will fix that part but scaling still have to be done externally as mentioned.